Is the decomposition $|0\rangle\langle0| \otimes \rho =( |0\rangle\otimes I_n)( I_A\otimes \rho)( \langle0|\otimes I_n) $ correct?
$
%\newcommand{\ketbra}[2]{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle\,\langle{#2}|}}
\newcommand{\ketbra}[1]{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle\,\langle{#1}|}}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle{#1}|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|{#1}\rangle}$
I am trying to calculate the partial trace of some operators and initial state is of the form $\ketbra{0}\otimes \rho$. It will largely simplify the calculation if I can make use of the decomposition  $|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes \rho = (\ket{0}\otimes I_n )(I_A\otimes\rho) (\bra{0}\otimes I_n)$. However, I feel the dimension of the matrix multiplication here is not consistent.
Another decomposition like
$\ketbra{0}\otimes \rho = (\ket{0}\otimes I_n) \rho (\bra{0}\otimes I_n)$
makes more sense to me. Specifically, if we are considering those operator in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then
$$
\ket{0} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0 \end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\rho = \begin{bmatrix}\rho_{11} & \rho_{12}\\\rho_{21} & \rho_{22} \end{bmatrix}. 
$$
It reveals that
$$
\ket{0}\otimes I_n = \begin{bmatrix}I_n\\0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
I_A\otimes\rho = \begin{bmatrix}\rho & 0\\0 & \rho \end{bmatrix},
$$
and the matrix multiplication is not doable as the number of columns of the first matrix should be equal to the number of rows of the second matrix.
I am not sure which decomposition is correct. I would really appreciate it if anyone can answer my questions.

Notation: \langle \phi \mid \psi \rangle produces $\langle \phi \mid \psi \rangle$. These are the proper angle brackets (that are extensible for surrounding bigger expressions) and vertical bar with proper white space.

The decomposition $|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes \rho = (\ket{0}\otimes I_n )(I_A\otimes\rho) (\bra{0}\otimes I_n)$ is correct, I'm not sure why you think that the dimension of the matrix multiplication is inconsistent

Thanks. Does that mean $I_A = I_1 = 1$ to make sure that $\mid 0 \rangle I_A \langle 0 \mid$ is well defined?

I don't know what step you're trying to simplify exactly, but the relation that seems more natural to me is
$$|0\rangle\langle0| \otimes \rho =( |0\rangle\!\langle 0|\otimes I_n)( I_A\otimes \rho)(|0\rangle\!\langle 0|\otimes I_n) $$
instead. Note the ket-bras avoiding your dimensional issue.
The object $|0\rangle I_A \langle 0|$, while I suppose you might find a consistent way to define it, is a bit weirder, while $|0\rangle\!\langle0| I_A |0\rangle\!\langle0|$ is a standard product of 3 operators/matrices.
